# Making Folders' Last Modified Date Correspond to Last Modified Date of It's Child Folders/Files

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

In 2018, after moving my files to another drive, the modified date of my folders is updated. Is there way to change folder's modified date based on the latest modified file in the folder?

The folder path is D:\Yeni klasör\complete
There are 800 subfolders even maybe more! All of them is in the "D:\Yeni klasör\complete" parent folder.

These subfolders contain mostly music files. Example of one folder called "2003-Harem" :

https://i.hizliresim.com/P7voqb.png

Look the modified date of the latest file of that "2003-Harem" :

https://i.hizliresim.com/2OvkkO.png

I want these subfolders to be be exact same date/time what they got in inside. Example 2003-Harem folder should be 20.04.2016

Is there way to do it with one Powershell code? I am so bad at CMD/Powershell so the parent folder path is at the top.

I am even more bad at describing about what i want. Please don't hesitate to ask if you did not understand anything. :D Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$Current_File  = Get-ChildItem "C:\My\Path\Here" -file -Recurse | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$Parent_Folder = Split-Path $Current_File.FullName
$Folder_Item   = Get-Item -Path $Parent_Folder

#Change "LastWriteTime" property to most current file
$Folder_Item.LastWriteTime = $Current_File.LastWriteTime
```

basically looks for the file with the most current time, and updates the parent folder to that time.

**EDIT:**

I haven't tested it out, but the logic is the same as what I commented so it should work. Test it on a few folders and not all of them first.

```
#Gather only the directories in your parent folder into a variable as an array
$Directory_Collection = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\My\Parent_Folder" -Directory

#Create a foreach loop to iterate through all the folders 
    foreach($DIrectory in $Directory_Collection){
        

        #Use the current directory its on to loop through,
        #and get the most current file to update the directory date to
        $Current_File  = Get-ChildItem $DIrectory.FullName  -file -Recurse | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
        $Parent_Folder = Split-Path $Current_File.FullName
        $Folder_Item   = Get-Item -Path $Parent_Folder

        #Change "LastWriteTime" property to most current file
        $Folder_Item.LastWriteTime = $Current_File.LastWriteTime
        }
```

Comment: It worked! Sir thank you so much but is there way to apply this to whole parent folder so it can change all subfolder's date. If it cannot be done, i will do it manually 1000 times,

Comment: Can you clarify, or give an example of what you mean? Is it just one parent folder?

Comment: Do you want to do the same thing for every folder in the directory of "complete"?

Comment: Yes sir! I want to do same thing for every folder in the directory of 'complete'.

Comment: Sure, that's easy enough but, I'm not sure you would be learning anything if I just write the script for you. How about if I explain it, and you write it, then we can see if you did it right together?

Comment: if your directory is "D:\somefolder\complete", just get every directory (folder) in that directory of "complete", save it to a variable as an array. Make a foreach loop to iterate though each directory, and just change the path on the code posted above  to directorys full name of the current folder/directory in the foreach loop. The same code above will work so you just have to gather each folder, and put the code above in a foreach loop. Does this make some sense?

Comment: I am using computers since 2001, fixed countless of problems, used hundreds of programs but never been able to use this Powershell thing. I am not good at math so that makes sense. I am curious person, I checked the commands what it means and I understood but I don't have any basic training due to that, I am not able to bring them together. It would be so much better if you write for me. Otherway I will feel like I am burden on your shoulders.

Comment: Most people don't want to write scripts  if you haven't tried it yourself, im not sure if it applies here too but, on StackOverflow you have to write your own script first. Then we help you troubleshoot. I'd recommend you writing some code first and other people could try to help. Will edit the code in about 3 minutes so just keep looking at the answer.

Comment: Just added the code now

Comment: It just worked! Before asking you i added "-Directory" command but it failed. Well, i would fail on writing foreach loop thing, I would not be able to write that for hours! I never ever forget your goodness in my life. You have solved my longtime problem. God bless you sir!

Comment: That's probably because you don't have that parameter; most likely due to the powershell you're on. You could use a `Where-Object` to find only the folders instead. Anyways, glad to help. Have a good one!

Comment: Also, foreach loops are basic in powershell. Just watch some youtube videos.